# Como criar um novo campo no post utilizando "meta_input" (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress

Estou tentando criar um novo campo em todos os `posts` com `post_type` `noo_company`, utilizando o `meta_input`, só que não está funcionando. Não está registrando e nem salvando os valores do campo no banco de dados, alguém poderia me ajudar?

Abaixo segue um trecho do código:

```
$company_data = array(
    'post_title'     => $company_name,
    'post_type'      => 'noo_company',
    'comment_status' => 'closed',
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'post_author'    => $user_id,
    'meta_input'     => array(
         'cnpj' => $_POST['user_cnpj']
    )
);

$company_id = wp_insert_post( $company_data );

if ( ! empty( $postarr['meta_input'] ) ) {
    foreach ( $postarr['meta_input'] as $field => $value ) {
            update_post_meta( $post_ID, $field, $value );
    }
} 

if( !is_wp_error( $company_id ) ) {
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'employer_company', $company_id );
    // Save custom fields
    jm_company_save_custom_fields( $company_id, $_POST );
}
```

Obs.: Estou tentando criar o campo "CNPJ". Os valores são recuperados de um formulário através do método POST.

Comment: O stack snippet (chamado de *trecho de código*) é obviamente usado para executar javascript, html e css, ou seja front-end, não tem porque usar stacksnippet para colocar php, c++, java, c#, isso nunca vai funcionar.

Comment: Trabalhe com os [campos personalizados](https://www.canalwp.com/codigos-wordpress/campos-personalizados-custom-fields-no-wordpress) do próprio Wordpress.